# Incompatibilities while upgrading from 9.0-8 to 9.0-10?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

We want to upgrade from `9.0-8 to 9.0-10`. I could not find any manual providing incompatibilities between the two versions of MarkLogic. The only incompatibilities between `9.0-8 to 9.0-9` is related to `MarkLogic SQL ORDER-BY Keyword` and we do not use `SQL` in our project at all.
There are bug fixes, new features which I can go through but when it comes to incompatibilities specifically there is no manual between `9.0-8/9.0-9 to 9.0-10`. Shall I presume that there are none ?

Answer (score 3):

MarkLogic puts New Feature notes and Incompatibility notes out for each major and minor version release to detail any enhancements, changes, or potential incompatibilities.  It's recommended to review both documents to ensure compatibility with your current application code.

Both lists are part of the [Release Notes](http://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/relnotes) Document.

- [New Features in MarkLogic 9](http://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/relnotes/chap3)
- [Known Incompatibilities with Previous Releases](http://Known%20Incompatibilities%20with%20Previous%20Releases)

If none are listed, then it's likely that there are no known incompatibilities.